# Rails: How to model "question has many answers but only one accepted answer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

Like on StackOverflow, there is a question and that question has many answers.
But only one of the answers is marked as accepted.
How to implement the same thing in Rails?

The models and tables I have are:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    has_one :accepted_answer # how to get this to work?
end
#Table: questions(id,question_text)

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
#Table: answers(id, question_id)
```

**UPDATE** (@voldy, thanks! But that doesn't seem to work?)
I added `belongs_to :accepted_answer, :class_name => 'Answer'` in the Question model.
Then added a `accepted_answer_id` and ran this code:

```
@question = current_user.questions.find(3)
an_answer = Answer.find(1) #presuming this is the answer i want to accept
@question.accepted_answer = an_answer
@question.save!
```

But the `accepted_answer_id` field in `questions` table remains null?
I also tried with field name as `answer_id`, but the same result.

Comment: Try `@question.answer_id = an_answer.id`. If you would like to use `accepted_answer_id` instead of `answer_id`, add `:foreign_key => "accepted_answer_id"` to relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are different approaches. One of them is to add answer_id to questions table:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    belongs_to :accepted_answer, :class_name => "Answer", 
                                 :foreign_key => :answer_id
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Somewhere in the view `if question.accepted_answer == answer` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried that but it doesnt seem to work? Please see the update to my question

Comment: I have added `:foreign_key` to relationship. Also see my comment to your question. And you should add this new field to `attr_accessible` if you use it (I encourage to use it).

Comment: Great! adding the `foreign_key` did the trick. One question: wouldn't making the field `attr_accessible` expose a risk : someone could change the accepted answer by sending a param to through the controller?

Comment: You are right! It was a midnight for me. Don't do it with this field  :).